# IOException when trying to import Excel XLSX file on Android

Tags: java, android, file, import, ioexception

I'm trying to make a simple app for importing & displaying an Excel file on Android using Java, but I keep getting an `IOException`.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: filepath/filename.xlsx: open failed:
> ENOENT (No such file or directory)

edit: I use a FilePickerActivity to search for a file I want to import.

```
    file_browse_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilePickerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.CONFIGS, new Configurations.Builder()
                .setCheckPermission(true)
                .setShowFiles(true)
                .setShowImages(false)
                .setShowVideos(false)
                .setMaxSelection(1)
                .setSuffixes("xls", "xlsx")
                .setSkipZeroSizeFiles(true)
                .build());

        do_file_browse.launch(intent);
    });
```

Method after I chose a file:

```
do_file_browse = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                String file_path;
                String file_name;
                Intent data = result.getData();
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    ArrayList<MediaFile> mediaFiles = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(FilePickerActivity.MEDIA_FILES);
                    file_path = mediaFiles.get(0).getPath();
                    file_name = mediaFiles.get(0).getName();

                    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(file_path), file_name);
                    readExcelDatas(file);
                }
            }
    );
```

Method for reading the file:

```
private void readExcelDatas(File file) {
    WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
    ws.setGCDisabled(true);
    if(file != null) {
        try {

            workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
            for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
                Cell[] row = sheet.getRow(i);
                first_name_list.add(row[0].getContents());
                second_name_list.add(row[1].getContents());
                phone_number_list.add(row[2].getContents());
                email_address_list.add(row[3].getContents());
            }
            showDatas();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong. (IOException)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong. (BiffException)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

This also doesn't work:
`workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(file.getName()));`

Comment: `File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(file_path), file_name);` -- this is almost certainly wrong. However, we do not know what you are using for this `startActivityForResult()` work, so it will be difficult to provide further advice.

Comment: Sorry! I edited the post.

Comment: Is `FilePickerActivity` from some library, or did you create it?

Comment: It's a library.
implementation 'com.github.jaiselrahman:FilePicker:1.3.2'

Comment: Based on that library documentation, it should be `File file = new File(file_path)`. `getPath()` is documented as returning "the absolute path to the file".

Comment: Oh, yes. You're right. Thank you. It helped a lot.